# how to plot with factor variables in r

Tags: r

I have a data frame df, with each row containing several variables. And I want to plot with x representing time.

```
 time <- df[,1]
 plot(0,0,xlim=c(time[1],time[length(time)]),ylim = range(rowSums(df[,2:3])), t="n")
```

But it doesn't work because the first column has factors, rather than variables. How to get the range of factor variables? Thanks.

```
df:
   date      v1  v2  v3  v4 ...
01/09/2012   12  13  11
01/12/2012   13  15  10
01/20/2012   14  16  20
02/11/2012   10  17  18
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert `date` to date format. There are a number of ways to do this, but the `lubridate` package makes it easy:

```
library(lubridate)
df$date = mdy(df$date)

range(df$date)

[1] "2012-01-09 UTC" "2012-02-11 UTC"

plot(df$date, df$v1)
```

[image]

Comment: For some reason, when you set the axis limits the way you're setting them in your code, R changes the x-axis value to numeric. The numeric values are the number of seconds since January 1, 1970, which is how the underlying date values are stored. You can get the x-axis in date format if you do this: `plot(df$date, df$v1, xlim=range(df$date))`. Then just adjust the range values to get them to what you want. For example, if you want to add one day to the range on each end, you can do `range(df$date) + c(-24*3600, 24*3600)` (where 24*3600 is the number of seconds in a day).

Comment: See [this article](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/faq/dates.htm) for more on how R handles date values. Also, here's the [`lubridate` Vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lubridate/vignettes/lubridate.html) for processing date with `lubridate`.